# bash execute svn command where url contains spaces

Tags: bash, svn, whitespace

I'm a newbie when it comes to linux and particularly bash scripting.

Basically what I want to do is (in some mixed bash / pseudo code)

```
for entry in `svn list https://svn.xxx.../projects`
  if already checked out
  then
    svn up https://svn.xxx.../projects/$entry some/local/path
  else 
    svn co https://svn.xxx.../projects/$entry some/local/path
  fi

  ... other stuff ...
done
```

My problem is that unfortunately some of our projects contains spaces in their names.
I managed to do some assembling of the 'entry' parts but when executing the subversion command the spaces in the url became escaped. E.g.

```
svn co "https://svn.xxx.../projects/$myassembly" some/local/path
```

becomes

```
svn co https://svn.xxx.../projects/Project%20With%20Space some/local/path
```

and the url could not be found.

I would appreciate any help on how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop and quotes where the variable is expanded. Feed the `while` loop using process substitution redirected into the `done`.

```
while read -r entry
do
  if already checked out
  then
    svn up "https://svn.xxx.../projects/$entry" some/local/path
  else 
    svn co "https://svn.xxx.../projects/$entry" some/local/path
  fi

  ... other stuff ...
done < <(svn list https://svn.xxx.../projects)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there were two things I couldn't get to work directly.
The first thing was the feeding into the loop, but I fixed that by writing to a file first.
The second thing is that the space still gets escaped
The following test script

    baseUrl=...
    svn list $baseUrl > /tmp/projects.txt
    while read -r entry
    do
      svn co --depth 'files' "$baseUrl/$entry/trunk" "/tmp/tmp2/$entry/trunk"
    done < /tmp/projects.txt

still produces outputs like this when there is a space in the URL
svn: URL:en ".../Some%20Project/trunk" finns inte

Comment: Thanks again. Got it working. It's embarrassing, but the reason for the error wasn't the %20, but rather that there for that project didn't exist a trunk sub folder... *shame*

Comment: Tried to vote up your answer but I didn't have enough reputation

Comment: @JörgenPersson: If you're using Bash, the process substitution should work. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I ran the following test script: while read -r entry
  echo $entry
done < <(svn list https://svn.xxx..../projects) 
and the output (translated from swedish): ./test.sh: line3: Syntax error close to the unexpected symbol "done"

Comment: @JörgenPersson: You're missing the `do` (and so am I in my answer - oops!).